# OS fingerprinting

Tags: operating-systems, sniffer, python, fingerprinting

I have been asked to write a small tool that detects the running OS on a victim device.

The tool should be able to fingerprint Linux versus Android versus iOS. Extra credit for version info. It needs to be done through analysing network traffic. Unfortunately, I know nothing about this, or how it works, or even how to get started. I would appreciate a lot if someone could help and give me starter code.

Comment: Go look at the nmap source code.

Comment: If ttl = 64 then it's linux.
If ttl = 128, then it's windows.
If ttl = 255, then it's a routing device or unix.  
If port 111 is open, then it's linux or unix.  
If port 135/139/445 are open, then it's windows.
Bear in mind these are all defaults and can be changed.

Comment: forgot to mention iOS is also 255

Comment: Github is full of tools that do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can passively determine the operating system by figuring out TTL's and Window Sizes from analyzing Wireshark packet captures.

These two sites may at least get you started:

http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-11&post=Passive-OS-Fingerprinting

https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/2009/i-have-a-pcap-file-and-im-trying-to-find-out-the-client-system

Comment: You can change your TTL in windows, and a lot of people do this.